# Angular 4: http interceptor emit events to other components?

Tags: angular, event-handling

I have a usual `http intercetor`, that makes a call to a certain API and if it receives a `403` response, must emit an event.

Interceptor:

```
@Injectable
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  @Output() notify: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.body.status === 403) {
      this.notify.emit(true);
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }

}
```

And then I have a `navi.component.html` that would listen for this event:

```
<md-toolbar (notify)="onNotify($event)">
  <a routerLink="/home">
      <img src="assets/images/logo.png" class="md-card-image p-navi-logo" alt="image caption"></a>
  <span class="spacer"></span>

  <div fxLayout="row" fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-sm>
    <development *ngIf="isLoggedIn"></development>
    <guide-menu></guide-menu>
    <documentation-menu></documentation-menu>
    <administration *ngIf="isAdmin"></administration>
    <about></about>
  </div>
...
```

`top-navi.component.ts`

```
public onNotify(result: boolean):void {
    console.log('notification received: ' + result);
    this.isLoggedIn = result;
  }
```

The problem is that the top-navi-component never gets the event and doesn't log anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use like `<md-toolbar (notify)="onNotify($event)">` instead of `<md-toolbar (notifyAccessDenied)="onNotify($event)">`

Comment: @Chandru it was like this in the project, I incorrectly renamed the values for stackoverflow. Still doesn't emit the event in the top-navi.component.ts

Comment: try emit method like `this.notify.next(true);` instead of `this.notify.emit(true);`

Comment: @Chandru tried this also before, didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try like this to emit value follow below steps

create new service file `or` if you have existing service file use that

**sample.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SampleService {
    notify: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
    onNotify(event) {
            this.notify.next(true);
    }
}
```

**Interceptor:**

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private sampleService: SampleService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (req.body.status === 403) {
            this.sampleService.onNotify(true)
        }
        return next.handle(req);
    }

}
```

and **navi.component.html**

```
<md-toolbar>
    <a routerLink="/home">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.png" class="md-card-image p-navi-logo" alt="image caption">
    </a>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-sm>
        <development *ngIf="isLoggedIn"></development>
        <guide-menu></guide-menu>
        <documentation-menu></documentation-menu>
        <administration *ngIf="isAdmin"></administration>
        <about></about>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

finally **top-navi.component.ts**

```
export class TopNaviComponent {

    constructor(private sampleService: SampleService) {

        this.sampleService.notify.subscribe((result) => {
            console.log('result', result)
        })

    }
}
```